# Is there any different of when clearInterval is called?

Tags: javascript

Part A:

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
  doSomething();
  if(...)
    clearInterval(interval);
}, 100);
```

Part B:

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
  if(...)
    clearInterval(interval);
  doSomething();
}, 100);
```

Is there any difference?

Comment: It _should_ behave the same, but I'm no expert.

Comment: Seen as `intervals` fire during the next tick, both should work the same.

Comment: I'd wonder - if `doSomething()` takes more than 100ms, would the first potentially call multiple times (the next interval would fire before being cleared), whereas the second ensures it won't?

Comment: @TylerRoper  In Chrome it makes no difference, but maybe other browsers it's different.

Answer (score 2):

While I don't think this holds true given your specific example, it's worth pointing out that these two *would* be different if your function was asynchronous.

Below, I've simulated `doSomething()` taking 500ms:

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function doSomething() {
    console.log("Hello world");
    await sleep(500);
}

var interval = setInterval(async function(){
  await doSomething();
  clearInterval(interval);
}, 100);
```

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function doSomething() {
    console.log("Hello world");
    await sleep(500);
}

var interval = setInterval(async function(){
  clearInterval(interval);
  await doSomething();
}, 100);
```

Comment: This is simulating a different problem.

Comment: @Keith I'm going to restore this but address the fact that it pertains specifically to asynchronous. Reason being, while it might not pertain to this exact example, I think it provides an example where moving `clearInterval()` *could* make a difference, which seems in the spirit of the question. Regardless I think your example is more appropriate given OP's code, so I've upvoted it.

Comment: I agree, it's a good idea to restore.  And pointing how `async / await` can change things make sense.

Answer (score 2):

In Chrome, I see no difference.

Here I'm even waiting 1200ms, and yet hello is only console logged once.

I've made a snippet here to test for other browsers..

The reason why it should only fire once, is because timers fire during next tick, so even if 100ms has passed, another set Interval cannot execute, but by the time it can execute the interval has cleared.

Saying all this it would be interesting to see if all browsers behave this way.

> Update:  Testing in Edge / IE11 / Chrome & Firefox, all work the same.  IOW: clearInterval before or after the function body makes no difference.

```js
var i = setInterval(function () {
  var t = new Date().getTime();
  while (new Date().getTime() - t < 1200) ;
  console.log("hello");
  clearInterval(i);
}, 100);
```